# Generating types from schema for TypeScript yields empty file

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I take [these steps](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-codegen#generate), which means, I first create the json:

```
apollo-codegen introspect-schema schema.graphqls --output schema.json
```

which yields:

```
{
  "data": {
    "__schema": {
      "queryType": {
        "name": "Query"
      },
      "mutationType": null,
      "subscriptionType": null,
      "types": [
        { 
          "kind": "OBJECT",
          "name": "Query",
          "description": "",
          "fields": [
            {

              ...
```

But after, when I run:

```
 apollo-codegen generate **/*.graphqls --schema schema.json --target typescript --output schema.ts
```

I get an empty `schema.ts` types file:

```
/* tslint:disable */
//  This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.
/* tslint:enable */
```

Ideas?

Comment: Did you resolve this ?

Comment: @Ced Sorry. It’s been a while. I don’t remember what approach i took.

Answer (score 1):

In your `apollo-codegen generate` line you're targeting `.graphl*s*` files. Should that be `.graphql`?

Which file(s) are you expecting the generator to match? It needs to have files that contain queries or mutations that would be run against your schema - it won't generate code for the schema itself:

> The purpose of this command is to generate types for query and mutation operations made against the schema (it will not generate types for the schema itself).

Source: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/developer-tooling.html#introspect